# How to reduce vocal strain when singing long duration high notes?

Tags: technique, voice

Usually when I hit songs that have long notes and are somewhat in my mid/high position in range my voice kind of tires out. I can sing the whole song again, but at these long note parts I just can't last very long.

My voice still kind of "tires out" till the end. I feel as if my muscles can't sustain that pitch anymore, and it just drops. I am using head voice when singing high notes. Now I can sing these songs but after or almost till the end I feel so strained. Sometimes I can't finish them.

Comment: Sorry if this seems cruel, but I am glad that someone else has this problem too!

Comment: It seems it was a breathing problem, too much breath, and not breathing properly through the diaphragm can wear off the voice, never thought could be a bigger problem. Ahh well. :)

Comment: Use some vibrato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was given about 'not breathing properly through the diaphragm' This is a profound statement, as most proponents of body singing tell us that we must sing 'with' the diaphragm..or at the very least...'use the diaphragm' to sing properly. Perhaps we could just simply sing 'through' and 'with' our souls? We could use our energy...wouldn't that be wonderful!!! Take care of all these sundry problems with the body singing business, no? It's a bit like watching people playing computer games, or people driving with a GPS....as my son Damon (who owns a computer business) says to ALL of them "don't get too attached to the MAP!!!!" Or, perhaps it may be like the people who demand that the Taoists say 'we must walk the centred path - looking neither to the left or right....' Perhaps the word was scented??? Maybe we could just wake up, and smell the Roses? This is but my humble opinion, based on 66 years of experiencing life and research in all it's wonderous forms. We need to but learn the 3 'R's - Relax - Relax - RELAX !!!! It's as simple as A.B.C. Awareness - Balance - Control. Dear friend Ivan, it is not your voice that tires out - it is your breath..the body will breathe better and more fully if we would but allow it...by simply letting go of our mind's attachment to it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem sometimes, too, so don't worry. I can suggest two things, though. Try singing scales and working your way up to the specific note(s) that you wish to sing. You can also try projecting your voice. But, don't get so loud that you are straining to be louder. I love to sing and I tried to sing really high notes when I first started and my choir director suggested these two things. They worked for me, so I hope this helps! Enjoy singing and don't forget to practice!

Answer (score 2):

try gradually warming up into your high range throughout the day.  I know when I wake up on saturdays all ultra stoked and start singing full steam my high range gets worn out